# Python append only unique names instead of duplicates

Tags: python, append, bots, overwrite

So its a bot for an online Im called chatango.
its a whitelist that shows who all are allowed to use the bot.

The code is :

```
whitelist = []
f = open("users/"+name+".txt", "r") # read-only
print("[INFO]LOADING WHITELIST-LVL-1...")
soundz("info")
time.sleep(1)
for name in os.listdir(path):
 if len(name.strip()[:-4])>0: whitelist.append(name.strip()[:-4])
f.close()
```

When i add one more person to the list using

```
 open("users/"+name+".txt", 'w')
```

and when it is reloaded it makes duplicates in the list

```
eg 
Before: man1,man2,man3 
[Reloaded] 
After: man1,man2,man3man1,man2,man3,man4
```

How do i make it

```
man1,man2,man3,man4 instead of man1,man2,man3man1,man2,man3,man4
```

after reload?

Please help

Comment: Short answer: use a set instead of a list.

Comment: You can either check if the string exists first before appending or use a set as Kevin suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a set instead ([Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) | [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)). Sets do not preserve the order of items but will contain only unique items, so you won't have duplicate entries.

```
whitelist = set()
f = open("users/"+name+".txt", "r")
print("[INFO]LOADING WHITELIST-LVL-1...")
soundz("info")
time.sleep(1)
for name in os.listdir(path):
    if len(name.strip()[:-4])>0: whitelist.add(name.strip()[:-4])
f.close()
```

Comment: will this work? if name not in os.listdir(path):
               whitelist.remove(name.strip()[:-4])
              f.close()

Comment: @Xei That should work. Check the documentation on sets

Answer (score 0):

I would check for the existence of the item in the white list and only add if not there:

So at the point where you want to append to whitelist:

```
if not name in whitelist:
    whitelist.append(name)
```